# Detect changes to global coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

### Problem

How can I detect changes to the global x y coordinates of a component (from within the component). By global coordinates, I mean coordinates relative to the stage, not the container.

It's easy enough to detect when `MyComponent.x` is changed, but not so easy when `MyComponent.parent.x` is changed.

---

### Example

In the below code, there is `#container` which holds `MyComponent`. The coordinates of `#container` depends on the `currentState`, but the coordinates of `MyComponent` remain the same in relation to `#container`.

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="state1" />
    <s:State name="state2" />
</s:states>

<s:Group id="container" x.state1="0" x.state2="35"
                        y.state1="0" y.state2="35">
    <local:MyComponent width="300" height="400" />
</s:Group>
```

In the above code, how can I detect when the position (relative to stage) of `MyComponent` has changed?

I need to do this from code within `MyComponent`, it's not good enough to simply call a function when the state is changing.

---

### Ideas

So far I have tried listening for `updateComplete`, `move`, `resize` etc.. but it doesn't work.

I have also considered listening for `enterStage` or listening for `move` on all parents, I think these options may be resource intensive and am hoping there's a better way.

---

### Reason

In the real code, I have wrapped `StageWebView` in a `UIComponent`, I'm running into problems when the parent's coordinates are changed. I have no way to listen for that event.

If you've worked with this class before, you'll know that it can't be added to the display list, instead it's attached to the stage. This makes it difficult to manage, I wanted to wrap it so that I could reuse directly in MXML.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try overriding the setters for x, y in that class plus its full line of parents.  That way you won't be listening to events, but you will be able to tell when x or y has been set through normal means.  However if you're also wanting to catch it when something like right or horizontalCenter causes stuff to move automatically, this won't work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I would have to override the props for each parent, right the way through. I need to do this within the single class MyComponent.

Comment: Adding an event listener to each parent would actually be preferable, at least this could be done dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MyComponentRef.transform.concatenatedMatrix` to get the transformations applied to it. The `tx` and `ty` property of the matrix will serve your purpose.

Comment: The problem is not finding the global position, it is detecting it's change. To get the global position I have been using localToGlobal.